# How to capture a print out of a function into a variable in R

Tags: r, string, function

I have the following function that return just a print out with `cat()`.

```
show_something <- function() {cat("foo\n")}
```

What I want to do is to capture the output fo that function into a variable as a string.

I tried this:

```
> x <- show_something()
foo
> x
NULL
>
```

As you can see `x` return NULL. How can I get `x` to capture `foo`?

Comment: Using `cat` in a function is usually bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` doesn't return anything but you can use `capture.output` here -

```
show_something <- function() {cat("foo\n")}
x <- capture.output(show_something())
x
#[1] "foo"
```